# How do you verify whether OpenStack instances are being backed up or not? Is there a way to do this using the GUI?

Tags: backup, centos7, openstack

How do you verify whether OpenStack instances are being backed up or not? Is there a way to do this using the GUI? The instances are running on Centos7

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, there are two method to create the `server backup`.

- create by command line `openstack server backup create`, it will use the **server name** while not define the `--name` optional argument.

```
usage: openstack server backup create [-h] [-f {json,shell,table,value,yaml}]
                                      [--name <image-name>]
                                      <server>
Create a server backup image
positional arguments:
  <server>              Server to back up (name or ID)
optional arguments:
  --name <image-name>   Name of the backup image (default: server name)
```

- create by the horizon GUI `create snapshot` button and have to define the snapshot name.
  [image]

So, you could get the instances's backup list through **images** list with some search filter, and the **Type** column could tell the create method, the **Visibility** column default to `Private` of the `server backup`, like this:
[image]

If you click the image name, you will see the `instance_uuid` of the original server in the **Custom Properties** block. In my experiment, you should get the whole cluster's backup servers list by some script, the horizon GUI functions are limited.